# Update the salary of each instructor to 10000 times the number of course sections they have taught

Tags: mysql, database

Instructor table

| ID | name | dept_name | salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10101 | Srinivasan | Comp. Sci. | 65000.00 |
| 12121 | Wu | Finance | 90000.00 |
| 15151 | Mozart | Music | 40000.00 |
| 22222 | Einstein | Physics | 95000.00 |
| 32343 | El Said | History | 60000.00 |
| 33456 | Gold | Physics | 87000.00 |
| 45565 | Katz | Comp. Sci. | 75000.00 |
| 58583 | Califieri | History | 62000.00 |
| 76543 | Singh | Finance | 80000.00 |
| 76766 | Crick | Biology | 72000.00 |
| 83821 | Brandt | Comp. Sci. | 92000.00 |
| 98345 | Kim | Elec. Eng. | 80000.00 |

Teaches table

| ID | course_id | sec_id | semester | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 76766 | BIO-101 | 1 | Summer | 2017 |
| 76766 | BIO-301 | 1 | Summer | 2018 |
| 10101 | CS-101 | 1 | Fall | 2017 |
| 83821 | CS-190 | 1 | Spring | 2017 |
| 83821 | CS-190 | 2 | Spring | 2017 |
| 83821 | CS-319 | 2 | Spring | 2018 |
| 10101 | CS-347 | 1 | Fall | 2017 |
| 98345 | EE-18 | 1 | Spring | 2017 |
| 22222 | PHY-101 | 1 | Fall | 2017 |

I tried this

```
update instructor 
set salary = 10000 * (
select count(distinct sec_id, semester, year)
from teaches 
where instruction.ID = teaches.ID);
```

Comment: update instructor 
    set salary = 10000 * (
    select count(distinct sec_id, semester, year)
    from teaches 
    where instruction.ID = teaches.ID);

Comment: What do you mean by `course section` ? Please show the expected result in the question as well

Comment: can take both course_id and sec_id as course section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if below approach is your expected result but it might give you a hint if is not  the solution to your problem.

```
CREATE TABLE instructor  (
  id int,
  name varchar(25),
  dept_name varchar(50),
  salary decimal(10,2) );

INSERT INTO instructor VALUES
(10101,'Srinivasan',"Comp. Sci.",65000.00),
(12121,'Wu','Finance',90000.00),
(15151,'Mozart','Music',40000.00),
(22222,'Einstein','Physics',95000.00),
(32343,'El Said','History',60000.00),
(33456,'Gold','Physics',87000.00),
(45565,'Katz','Comp. Sci.',75000.00),
(58583,'Califieri','History',62000.00),
(76543,'Singh','Finance',80000.00),
(76766,'Crick','Biology',72000.00),
(83821,'Brandt','Comp. Sci.',92000.00),
(98345,'Kim','Elec. Eng.',80000.00);


CREATE TABLE teaches (
  id int,
  course_id varchar(25),
  sec_id int,
  semester varchar(20),
  year int  );

INSERT INTO teaches VALUES
(76766,'BIO-101',1,'Summer',2017),
(76766,'BIO-301',1,'Summer',2018),
(10101,'CS-101',1,'Fall',2017),
(83821,'CS-190',1,'Spring',2017),
(83821,'CS-190',2,'Spring',2017),
(83821,'CS-319',2,'Spring',2018),
(10101,'CS-347',1,'Fall',2017),
(98345,'EE-18',1,'Spring',2017),
(22222,'PHY-101',1,'Fall',2017);


update instructor i
inner join 
      (  select id,
                count(distinct course_id)  as cource_id_count
         from teaches 
         group by id
      ) as t1 on t1.id=i.id 
set i.salary= 10000 * t1.cource_id_count;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2a33159d87254d3a39535ccd9bf542d3

Check for more details on update :https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html

Comment: Thanks. This is what I wanted. But it shows "Error Code: 3819. Check constraint 'instructor_chk_1' is violated" when I execute it.

Comment: I found the error. It's working now.Thankyou